# How to delete directory?

Tags: git, web, github, directory

I'm working on a partner's repository code, and have been using the github.com web interface to directly make changes to the existing files - which has all been pretty straightforward.

However, I now need to delete a directory in the repository but this doesn't seem possible via the github.com web interface.

I have tried forking and cloning the repository, making my changes, committing, syncing, then doing a Pull Request - but the problem with that is that the partner (who owns the original repository) isn't around to accept the Pull Request, and I am just sat here waiting needlessly...

Like with modifying the contents of a single file, is there a real time / instant solution for deleting a directory?

Comment: If you don't have access to the repository, you can not delete files (or directories) there.

Comment: I *do* have access to the repository.

Comment: They you can accept the pull request with deleting files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to have write access to the original repo, there was no need to fork it. Just clone the repo directly (GitHub will show you appropriate urls at the top of the repo page), remove the folder/file with [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm), then commit the change, and push to the GitHub remote.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I was following these guidelines - https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo .

Comment: The help article might not explicitly mention your use case. A repo that you have write access is basically the same as one of your own repos, from your point of view. So instead of following the forking guide, look at the guides talking about your own repos.